KQL merge rows with the same ID into one row
I have a lot of log data that has some duplicate values except for two columns. The simplified query looks like this:
AzureActivity
| project TimeGenerated, CorrelationId, Caller, Action, RoleId, ObjectId

This gives me a table that looks like this:



TimeGenerated
CorrelationId
Caller
Action
RoleId
ObjectId
Status




8/13/2024, 4:09:34.099 PM
1
John Doe
Delete
222
333
Success


8/13/2024, 4:09:35.099 PM
1
John Doe
Delete


Start


8/15/2024, 8:09:34.099 PM
2
John Doe
Write
444
555
Success


8/15/2024, 8:09:35.099 PM
2
John Doe
Write


Start


8/19/2024, 1:09:34.099 PM
3
John Doe
Write
666
777
Success


8/19/2024, 1:09:36.099 PM
3
John Doe
Write


Start



I would like the table to look like this:



TimeGenerated
CorrelationId
Caller
Action
RoleId
ObjectId
Status




8/13/2024, 4:09:34.099 PM
1
John Doe
Delete
222
333
Success


8/15/2024, 8:09:34.099 PM
2
John Doe
Write
444
555
Success


8/19/2024, 1:09:34.099 PM
3
John Doe
Write
666
777
Success



Anyone has any tips on how to get this to work?
I have tried to summarize by the correlation ID, but I will either still have duplicate rows or missing rows. I have tried to look for other solutions, but can't seem to find anything that works for this specific case.

Another (similar) solution would be to control which elements take_any() will choose with prev() and order by, like that:
datatable(TimeGenerated:datetime, CorrelationId:long, Caller:string, Action:string, RoleId:long, ObjectId:long, Status:string)
[
    datetime(8/13/2024, 4:09:35.099 PM), 1, 'John Doe', 'Delete', 111, long(null), 'Start',
    datetime(8/19/2024, 1:09:36.099 PM), 3, 'John Doe', 'Write', long(null), long(null), 'Start',
    datetime(8/15/2024, 8:09:35.099 PM), 2, 'John Doe', 'Write', long(null), long(null), 'Start',
    datetime(8/13/2024, 4:09:34.099 PM), 1, 'John Doe', 'Delete', 222,  333, 'Success',
    datetime(8/15/2024, 8:09:34.099 PM), 2, 'John Doe', 'Write',  444,  555, 'Success',
    datetime(8/19/2024, 1:09:34.099 PM), 3, 'John Doe', 'Write',  666,  777, 'Success',
]
| order by CorrelationId, RoleId, ObjectId
| where prev(CorrelationId) != CorrelationId
| summarize take_any(*) by CorrelationId

This Query will only choose non-empty fields (if existing) of RoleId and ObjectId. Without that take_any() would just choose random matching CorrelationIds.


This worked perfectly for me, thanks for that! Afterwards I had to sort again by Time to make sure everything was displayed how we wanted it again.

you could try using the take_any() aggregation function - which could work for the data set you've provided (it may not work for you actual data set, but since you didn't provide that, it's not possible to determine that based on information provided in your question)
datatable(TimeGenerated:datetime, CorrelationId:long, Caller:string, Action:string, RoleId:long, ObjectId:long, Status:string)
[
    datetime(8/13/2024, 4:09:34.099 PM), 1, 'John Doe', 'Delete', 222,  333, 'Success',
    datetime(8/13/2024, 4:09:35.099 PM), 1, 'John Doe', 'Delete', long(null), long(null), 'Start',
    datetime(8/15/2024, 8:09:34.099 PM), 2, 'John Doe', 'Write',  444,  555, 'Success',
    datetime(8/15/2024, 8:09:35.099 PM), 2, 'John Doe', 'Write',long(null), long(null), 'Start',
    datetime(8/19/2024, 1:09:34.099 PM), 3, 'John Doe', 'Write',  666,  777, 'Success',
    datetime(8/19/2024, 1:09:36.099 PM), 3, 'John Doe', 'Write',long(null), long(null), 'Start',
]
| summarize take_any(*) by CorrelationId




CorrelationId
TimeGenerated
Caller
Action
RoleId
ObjectId
Status




1
2024-08-13 16:09:34.0990000
John Doe
Delete
222
333
Success


2
2024-08-15 20:09:34.0990000
John Doe
Write
444
555
Success


3
2024-08-19 13:09:34.0990000
John Doe
Write
666
777
Success



